# How to use aggregate from "meteorhacks" in Angular2-Meteor application

Tags: angular, meteor, aggregate, angular2-meteor

I am using "aggregate" by "meteorhacks" in Angular2-Meteor application.

I have already add this package and its working fine and good, but the problem is that I am getting a warning which is:

> Property 'aggregate' does not exist on type 'Collection< Attendance>'.

I have a collection of Attendances where I am using aggregate...

I and my collection constant is:

```
export const Attendances = new MongoObservable.Collection<Attendance>("attendances");
```

So I have try to use aggregate by pipeline in which we store aggregate array in a variable and than use that variable in aggregate.

And my aggregate code looks like this:

```
let totalBonus = Attendances.collection.aggregate(['my queries and $match']);
```

So how can I use aggregate without warning?

I have try to remove "collection" before aggregate and but it won't work!

Kindly help me with with warning, Thanks in advance...

Please don't thumb down my question... :)

Comment: I have tried to call in "typing.d.ts" file but it won't work also... 
so how can I use it without warning... please help me guys... I am waiting for you golden replies...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the file that uses the function:

`/// <reference path="..path../declarations.d.ts" />`

And put this in the declarations.d.ts file:

```
declare module Mongo {

interface Collection {
    aggregate(args:any, filter:any): Array<any>;
}
```

}